# Unable to find source map files in Safari 8

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-web-inspector

When in the Resources or Debugger of Safari 8 (10600.1.25.1), there appears to be no way to direct way access files via source maps.

For example, I have an `app.js` that is created with Browserify from e.g. `src/a.coffee` and `src/b.coffee` (and compiled with Coffeescript). If I pause Javascript while these are running the debugger will show the original Coffeescript source (via the source map) where it stopped e.g. `src/a.coffee`.

However, the Resources section does not show any way to get to `src/a.coffee` or `src/b.coffee` (other than pausing the Javascript and hoping it's in the right file). The compiled `app.js` is under `Scripts/`, but nothing else appears.

Clearly Safari is respecting the SourceMap when the debugger is paused, but I cannot find any documentation that reveals how one is expected to open up files included via source map.

The source maps work fine in Chrome.

Is anyone else getting a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very intuitive on Safari 8.

You should be able to find on Resources, under Extra Scripts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the post, fmgasparino. I am afraid that there is no "Extra Scripts" folder appearing for me. :/ I appreciate the post though. Cheers